# Delete operation in my webAPI controller where id is a filename

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API controller used for file manager with the following actions (so far):

```
[HttpPost] 
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    ...
}

[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(string filename)
{
    ...
}
```

So I have the opportunity to ...

- uploading new files with the **post** action
- downloading existing files with the **get** action
- deleting an existing file with the **delete** action.

I'm not sure about the `Delete` action. Usually (in a CRUD) we pass an id (with the integer type) to the Delete action method in order to retrieve a record based on his id. Here I'm passing a filename which is maybe not a goot practice.

**My question**: how can I proceed to manage my Delete action for deleting my files in my web API fileManager controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily see a problem with using a string as the ID, depending on the scope of what you're doing.  If you're managing files within the same folder on a Windows PC (server), for instance, you can't have more than one file with the same name.  So filename is unique enough.

If you are concerned about that, you can store a list of the files you're managing in a database, and assign a unique ID (say, an int) to each file.  That way you can reference that value on the backend when you do your deletes.